# The reason behind huge performance difference between two custom key implementations for std::unordered_set and how to fix it?

Tags: c++, optimization, customization, hashcode, unordered-set

I have some simple class with several fields like this:

```
#ifndef XVector_h
#define XVector_h

struct XVFields
{
    unsigned char JointPromosCountSinceBeginning;
    unsigned char PromoWeeksCountSinceCurrPromoBeginning;
    unsigned char NoPromoWeeksCountSinceLastJointPromo;
    bool IsPromo;
};

class XVector
{
public:
    XVFields XVFs;
    unsigned char *DiscountUsagesCounts;

    XVector();
    ~XVector();    
};

#endif XVector_h
```

It's realization:

```
#include <sstream>
#include "XVector.h"
#include "DynProgTask.h"

XVector::XVector()
{
    memset(&this->XVFs, 0, sizeof(XVFields));
    this->DiscountUsagesCounts = (unsigned char*)malloc(DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);
    memset(this->DiscountUsagesCounts, 0, DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);
    this->UniqueValForHuman_private = NULL;
}

XVector::~XVector()
{
    free(this->DiscountUsagesCounts);
}
```

I Have another class named `TaskCase` that has `XVector` as one of it's field. Single `TaskCase` - single `XVector`.

I have custom hashers and comparators for both of classes:

```
#ifndef XVectorHasher_h
#define XVectorHasher_h

#include <Windows.h>
#include "XVector.h"

struct XVectorHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const XVector *k) const;
};

struct XVectorComparator
{
    bool operator()(const XVector *xv1, const XVector *xv2) const;
};

#endif XVectorHasher_h
```

cpp:

```
#include "XVectorHasher.h"
#include "DynProgTask.h"

size_t XVectorHasher::operator()(const XVector *k) const
{
    size_t result = 0;
    const size_t prime = 31;

    int unibytes_count = sizeof(XVFields) + (DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);
    unsigned char *unibytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(unibytes_count);
    memcpy(unibytes, &k->XVFs, sizeof(XVFields));
    memcpy(&unibytes[sizeof(XVFields)], k->DiscountUsagesCounts, DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < unibytes_count; i++)
        result = unibytes[i] + (result * prime);

    free(unibytes);

    return result;
}

bool XVectorComparator::operator()(const XVector *xv1, const XVector *xv2) const
{   
    //this operator compares instances bytes to determine their equality
    if (memcmp(&xv1->XVFs, &xv2->XVFs, sizeof(XVFields)) != 0)
        return false;

    if (memcmp(xv1->DiscountUsagesCounts, xv2->DiscountUsagesCounts, DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Another h:

```
#ifndef TaskCaseHasher_h
#define TaskCaseHasher_h

#include <Windows.h>
#include "TaskCase.h"

struct TaskCaseHasher
{
    size_t operator()(const TaskCase *k) const;
};

struct TaskCaseComparator
{
    bool operator()(const TaskCase *xv1, const TaskCase *xv2) const;
};


#endif TaskCaseHasher_h
```

Another cpp:

```
#include "XVector.h"
#include "TaskCaseHasher.h"
#include "DynProgTask.h"

size_t TaskCaseHasher::operator()(const TaskCase *tc) const
{
    size_t result = 0;
    const size_t prime = 31;
    XVector *k = const_cast<TaskCase*>(tc)->GET_CurrX();

    int unibytes_count = sizeof(XVFields) + (DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);
    unsigned char *unibytes = (unsigned char*)malloc(unibytes_count);
    memcpy(unibytes, &k->XVFs, sizeof(XVFields));
    memcpy(&unibytes[sizeof(XVFields)], k->DiscountUsagesCounts, DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < unibytes_count; i++)
        result = unibytes[i] + (result * prime);

    free(unibytes);

    return result;
}

bool TaskCaseComparator::operator()(const TaskCase *tc1, const TaskCase *tc2) const
{
    //this operator compares instances bytes to determine their equality
    XVector *xv1 = const_cast<TaskCase*>(tc1)->GET_CurrX();
    XVector *xv2 = const_cast<TaskCase*>(tc2)->GET_CurrX();

    if (memcmp(&xv1->XVFs, &xv2->XVFs, sizeof(XVFields)) != 0)
        return false;

    if (memcmp(xv1->DiscountUsagesCounts, xv2->DiscountUsagesCounts, DynProgTask::PresetUsCount/* * sizeof(unsigned char)*/) != 0)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

I have self made single directional list of `TaskCase` pointers. I iterate over them to find unique `TaskCases` (the ones which has different XVectors).

I have two different functions for that:

```
SmartArray<TaskCase*> *TaskStep::GET_UniqueCasesByCurrX() //This one doing it's job in 191 second
{
    SmartArray<TaskCase*> *unitcs = new SmartArray<TaskCase*>(this->Cases->Length);
    std::unordered_set<XVector*, XVectorHasher, XVectorComparator> unique_xs;
    int curr_unique_case_i = 0;

    for (TaskCase *itr = this->Cases->Head; itr; itr = itr->NEXT_CASE_PTR)
        if (unique_xs.find(itr->GET_CurrX()) == unique_xs.end())
        {
            unique_xs.insert(itr->GET_CurrX());
            unitcs->Data[curr_unique_case_i] = itr;
            curr_unique_case_i++;
        }   

    unitcs->Resize(curr_unique_case_i);

    return unitcs;
}

std::unordered_set<TaskCase*, TaskCaseHasher, TaskCaseComparator> *TaskStep::GET_UniqueCasesSetByCurrX() //This one doing it's job in 363 seconds
{
    std::unordered_set<TaskCase*, TaskCaseHasher, TaskCaseComparator> *unique_tcs = new std::unordered_set<TaskCase*, TaskCaseHasher, TaskCaseComparator>();

    for (TaskCase *itr = this->Cases->Head; itr; itr = itr->NEXT_CASE_PTR)
        if (unique_tcs->find(itr) == unique_tcs->end())
            unique_tcs->insert(itr);    

    return unique_tcs;
}
```

`std::unordered_set` based on XVectors (191 sec) is way faster than `std::unordered_set` based on TaskCases (363 sec).
But I don't understand why. Anyway it falls to calling `GET_CurrX()` which returns `XVector`. In first case I can it by myself and in second case it called automatically inside set. What is possible to do to speedup `TaskCase` set?

Comment: What do you mean by "Anyway it falls to calling GET_CurrX() which returns XVector." ?

Comment: @foolo - Umm, I mean anyway instances comparison made by comparing `XVectors`. In first case I call `GET_CurrX()` by myself and use `XVectors` as keys, in second case I use `TaskCases` as key, but the comparison still made by calling `GET_CurrX()`.

Comment: OK. Only reason I can think of is that the hash function causes more hash collisions in the second case, otherwise they look identical. (or it could be the GET_CurrX calls, but that seems unlikely, if GET_CurrX is only a get function). But it's hard to answer without having an example. You could probably try to simplify the code and then try to produce a minimal example that still has the difference.

Comment: @foolo - Thank you for trying to help. I will see what I can do.